# Maven resolve property placeholder

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm using [jdeb](https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb/blob/master/docs/maven.md) to generate debian package and I need to specify dependencies in the debian control file. It looks as follows:

```
Depends: [[custom.runtime.library]]
```

where the `custom.runtime.library` property is generated as a concatenation of `libfoo` and `${project.versionMajor}` generated by [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) as

```
<properties>
    <custom.runtime.library>libfoo${project.versionMajor}</custom.runtime.library>
</properties>
```

The problem is the depends section of `debian.control` is resolved to

```
Depends: libfoo${project.versionMajor}
```

and then the package is obviously failed to install.

Is there a way to sort of pre-resolve maven properties?

Comment: have you tried with `@{project.versionMajor}`

Comment: @guido Just tried... The property was not replaced either... It seems the only way to pass it to the control file is to manually write it as `libfoo[[project.versionMajor]]`